# How to disable a <li></li> tag?

Tags: html, css

I developed some code. Now I would like to give a certain list-item a disabled look like bootstrap. How can I do this?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled">Disabled Primary</button>


<li id="abc" style="width:200px;border:solid 1px #b4123d;background-color:#4827a1;height:110px;margin-right:5px;line-height:45px;" >
 <span class="icon" style=" width:5px; height:5px; margin-top:-25px; margin-left:55px;">
    <i aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user " true"></span></i>
 </span>
 <span style=" font-weight:bold; font-size:16px; line-height:85px; margin-left:65px;">Admin</span>
</li>
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly? You want to remove styling from all those elements?

Comment: add `<!--` code to disable `-->`  ?

Comment: What do you mean by  Disabled ?

Comment: Are you talking about the disabled attribute?

Comment: I mean like a bootstrap button disabled(<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled">Disabled Primary</button>), how can i do it  <li> tag

Comment: A button is an action item - disable makes sense, but a list is just structured text. What are you expecting to happen to a disabled list?

Comment: this li tag is a some tile , like a windows 8.1 metro tile, i want to disable it. after user login. is is a admin part , im developed the code for function but i want to added disabled icon

Comment: A windows 8.1 metro tile? That's a button which also displays some information. You should use a `<button>` element if you want to create something like that.

Comment: thanks for the advice and help, iam founded my own solution this method, fine its working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**yeah finaly its working, im founded the my own method**

```
<li id="abc" style=" width:200px;border:solid 1px #b4123d;background-color:#b4123d;height:110px;margin-right:5px;line-height:45px;" class="btn  btn-primary disabled">

                            <span class="icon" style=" width:5px; height:5px; margin-top:-25px; margin-left:55px;">
                                <i aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user " true"></span></i>
                            </span>
                            <span style=" font-weight:bold; font-size:16px; line-height:85px; margin-left:65px;">Admin</span>



                    </li>
```

Comment: Inline styling is not realy the way to go. Use classes for specific styling and common styling. This way your code will be more readable and organized.

Answer (score 4):

Just add another class for eg `.disabled` to the list-item which you want to be disabled.

Give it another styling so it looks like it is disabled.

Comment: thanks for the help :)